# lower_bound function is returning the wrong iterator

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector

In the following code both 7 and 4 are returning the same value i.e. 2 meanwhile every else number is returning the right index

```
#include<iostream>
#include<algorithm>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    vector<int> v;

    v.push_back(1);
    v.push_back(3);
    v.push_back(7);
    v.push_back(4);
    v.push_back(9);
    cout<<"lower bound : "<<lower_bound(v.begin(),v.end(),7)-v.begin()<<endl;
    cout<<"lower bound : "<<lower_bound(v.begin(),v.end(),4)-v.begin()<<endl;
}
```

output:

```
lower bound : 2
lower bound : 2
```

I don't understand what's wrong with the code.

Answer (score 3):

The `vector` should be sorted in advance. E.g.

```
std::sort(v.begin(), v.end());
cout<<"lower bound : "<<lower_bound(v.begin(),v.end(),7)-v.begin()<<endl; // ->3
cout<<"lower bound : "<<lower_bound(v.begin(),v.end(),4)-v.begin()<<endl; // ->2
```

Answer (score 0):

`lower_bound` finds the first element that's greater-or-equal than the third parameter.

So `lower_bound(v.begin(),v.end(),4)` corretly finds `7`.

On the other hand, `lower_bound(v.begin(),v.end(),4)` causes undefined behavior since your vector [violates the precondition](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound):

> The range `[first, last)` must be partitioned with respect to the expression `element < value` or `comp(element, value)`, i.e., all elements for which the expression is true must precede all elements for which the expression is false. A fully-sorted range meets this criterion.